# WindowInsetsController#hide(statusBars()) causes content to jump

Tags: android, android-appcompat, insets

At the moment my activity calls

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
window.setFlags(FLAG_FULLSCREEN, FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

inside of its `onCreate` method in order to hide the status bar and display in fullscreen mode.

As part of the migration to Android 30 I replace `window.setFlags(FLAG_FULLSCREEN, FLAG_FULLSCREEN)` with `WindowInsetsController#hide(statusBars())` as documentation suggests. However, the behaviour of these two approaches is not the same. While the deprecated one smoothly hides the status bar the modern one makes the content of the activity to "jump" when the status bar is hidden.

Has anybody observed the same behaviour and found a fix for it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it fits your specific purpose since I had to rework my code a lot for a satisfactory solution, but I managed to get rid of the "jumping" with the following code in my Activity (I use the Compat classes to avoid having to code multiple implementations, but the original classes work the same):

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSystemUI();
    }
}

private void hideSystemUI() {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);

    WindowInsetsControllerCompat insetsController =   WindowCompat.getInsetsController(getWindow(), getWindow().getDecorView());
    if (insetsController != null) {
        insetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
        insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars());
        insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars());
    }
}
```

I had a toggling solution before which showed the system and navigation bar on touch (quite similar to [the now deprecated documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive), but I was not able to make it work without jumping.

What made the difference for me was to use `WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE`. The documentation about this option says the following:

> These transient system bars will overlay app’s content, may have some degree of transparency, and will automatically hide after a short timeout.

By the way, since [the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive) still uses deprecated code as of today I marked it as "unusable documentation" down below in the hope that it will get updated sooner.

Comment: In the end I developed almost the same solution

Comment: I have noticed the 'jumping' when using the hide/show in portrait orientation. In landscape orientation, there is no 'jumping'. The transient showing of bars solution is not good enough for me, because I want more customization. It looks like you can use the hide/show solution and still keep the window flags for fullscreen and avoid the jumping. In landscape mode, using fullscreen mode with hide/show messes up. So I am thinking of using fullscreen flag in portrait, and resetting the flags in landscape.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin version used in my app

`

```
private fun setToFullScreen() {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

    val insetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
    insetsController.systemBarsBehavior =
            WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.statusBars())
    insetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())
}
```

`